# SharePoint Server 2007 and HTML Forms - How to control access rights

Tags: sharepoint

I'm working with Hosted SharePoint 2007 with Forms Server. I need to allow client access to submit HTML forms designed in Infopath. Problem is, I need to make sure the clients don't see the library. There is sensitive data that will be on these forms. I also need to have a repeated library that is based on the Internal Admin records and requirements.
Outside of making a seperate library per customer, does anyone have any suggestions?

My Goal: 
1: Customers enter their requests through a link or provided page
2: Internally address the requests and perform required arrangements, add billing and payment fields
3: Have SharePoint metrics, reports, etc... based on the provided intormation and status.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I am torn between SF and SO. This is both programming and configuration.

Comment: i suggest this be moved to SF, as the answers given so far boil down to configuration steps.

Answer (score 1):

Make your library read only.  Create new permission level that only allows add but not delete and not edit.

You could also make a custom workflow with SharePoint designer that will automatically move a document from the insecure "drop box" library to a more secure library on all items that are added.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I was able to sucessfully achieve what I wanted. The method was to create special users groups with only add and edit permissions, nothing else. Publish the template in a public directory, but have it submit to the secure library, which they only have the add/edit permissions for. They cannot view the library it submits to, but the form will query and submit with no issue.

Thanks for the ideas.